# Why is there a random noise in my Bose QC35 II headphones when connected to Windows 10 via Bluetooth, when the microphone is on?

Tags: windows-10, bluetooth, microphone, noise, bose

My Bose QC35 II headphone is connected to Windows 10 via Bluetooth:

[image]

When the microphone is on, there is a random noise in my Bose QC35 II headphones. Why?

I don't have this issue when my Bose QC35 II headphones are connected to an iPad, iPhone, Galaxy S9 or Pixel 6.

E.g., I hear the noise when going to Sound -> Recording:

[image]

or in Audacity when recording:

[image]

or in Chrome when using the microphone, e.g. on https://voice.google.com/

---

BlueTooth chip that is inside my machine (MSI GS76 Stealth 11UH laptop), via [HWiNFO v7.34](https://www.hwinfo.com/download/):

```
[Port14] : Intel, PID=800A
    
[Device Information]
Device Manufacturer:    Intel
Product Name:           Intel, PID=800A
Serial Number:  -
USB Version Supported:  2.01
USB Device Speed:       USB 1.1 Full-speed
Driver Description:     Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)
Hardware ID:            USB\VID_8087&PID_0032
        
[Driver Information]
Driver Manufacturer:    Intel Corporation
Driver Description:     Intel(R) Wireless Bluetooth(R)
Driver Provider:        Intel Corporation
Driver Version:         22.70.0.3
Driver Date:            08-Jul-2021
DeviceInstanceId        - 
Location Paths          PCIROOT(0)#PCI(1400)#USBROOT(0)#USB(14)
```

Comment: Noise like that typically is EMI

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks. Sorry, I should have mentioned that there is no noise when the microphone is off and the headphones just play some music or do nothing.

Comment: What BT device do you have? Is it one of those very noisy (EMI) devices that are both WiFI and BT?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a Bose QC35 II headphone. No pb when connected to an iPad, iPhone, Galaxy S9 or Pixel 6.

Comment: I am talking about the BlueTooth device the Bose device connects to. **I want to know the BlueTooth chip that is inside your machine.** You can just [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment.

Comment: @Ramhound thanks, added

Comment: Bluetooth is a digital connection. I very much doubt it is subject to _audible_ electric interference. // Keep in mind that while the microphone is active, the super low quality “Hands-free Profile” is used. The switch could cause minor clicking or similar. Or are we talking about continuous noise? If so, could you perhaps describe it in greater detail? Is it white noise or pink noise or does it sound like coil whine…?